# Entity Framework 4 throws System.Data.UpdateException when deleting object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF4.0 and I'm trying to delete a record from the database, but my code keeps throwing the following exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.UpdateException'
>   occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

Here's my code:

```
public bool ApproveUser(string username)  
{
    using (var context = new UserRegistrationEntities())
    {
        // The entry object gets populated correctly
        var entry = context.PendingApprovals
                .Where(e => e.Username.Equals(username))
                .FirstOrDefault();
        try
        {
            context.DeleteObject(entry);
            // Also tried context.PendingApprovals.DeleteObject(entry)
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I've stepped through the code and the exception is being thrown at `context.SaveChanges();`

Am I missing anything? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `entry` is being populated correctly? `FirstOrDefault` may be creating a new object that doesn't exist in the collection.

Comment: @klugerama I'm 100% sure. All of `entry`'s fields match the record in my database table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the breakpoint and see if entry has value or not? Try this?

```
public bool ApproveUser(string username)  
{
    using (var context = new UserRegistrationEntities())
    {
        // The entry object gets populated correctly
        var entry = context.PendingApprovals
                .First(e => e.Username.Equals(username))
        if (entry != null) {
        try
        {
            context.PendingApprovals.DeleteObject(entry);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it first:

```
public bool ApproveUser(string username)  
{
    using (var context = new UserRegistrationEntities())
    {
        // The entry object gets populated correctly
        var entry = context.PendingApprovals
                .Where(e => e.Username.Equals(username))
                .FirstOrDefault();
        try
        {
            context.PendingApprovals.Remove(entry);
            context.DeleteObject(entry);
            // Also tried context.PendingApprovals.DeleteObject(entry)
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```